# SQL return additional information from the query

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I want to return most sold product from `orders` table and have a query for that,

I also want to include images of that product, which is in another table called `product`.

This is what I have so far:

```
select pid,SUM(quantity) as quan
from orders
group by pid
order by sum(quantity) desc;
```

Comment: Could you please post your `product` table schema? I would imagine it's something along these lines: `select orders.pid,SUM(orders.quantity) as quan, product.image
from orders join product on orders.pid = product.pid
group by pid
order by sum(quantity) desc;`

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to join that table.
If pid = product id then:

```
SELECT     orders.pid, SUM(orders.quantity) as quan, product.image_column
FROM       orders
LEFT JOIN  product
ON (
    orders.pid = product.id
)
GROUP BY orders.pid
ORDER BY quan desc;
```

Replace id in product.id with actual id which you can pair with orders table. In select replace image_column in product.image_column with actual column name that holds image data.